# Marketing API: New ads stops delivery on the entire ad account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have been creating new campaigns + a couple of ad sets and a single ad within each ad set using the Marketing API.

While the ad accounts work just fine when we create ads using the Facebook interfaces, those created using the API causes the entire account to stop delivering any ads for approximately 24 hours. Then it magically starts working.

Is there any documented or practical reason why this could happen? The access tokens are from application owners obtained and extended using graph api explorer.

Updates and read calls to API works without issues. It's just creating ads causing issues.

Any ideas?

Edit: We did contact the Ads support team and they said there does not seem to be any issues with the accounts.

Comment: Ads are first audited although. Please make sure that while creating ads/ad-set/campaign from API all parameters are correct, including ad-set startTime.